# .Net framework - "unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application"

Tags: c#, installation, .net-framework-version

Machine with /Net framework version 4.0 installed m/c (win xp with sp3) (no previous framework version present) 
when try to run the program which is compiled in framework previous version of .net framework  i.e =>3.5 ,came across below initialization error "***unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application***".
on googling found -[changing config](http://neilblackburn.blogspot.com/2009/10/net-framework-40-backward-compatibility.html) `<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>` may help to solve, but that too didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't he just install the older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to solve this issue.
Below info would be a help for someone who is in my situation.

insert below startup tag in your application.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

May be this blog entry would also be helpful: [NET 4.0 and Mixed-mode assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2009/11/17/f-scripting-net-4-0-and-mixed-mode-assemblies.aspx)