# " error unable to find version at runtime"

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an application in VS2010 actually I updated the application which was a VS2008 version  so now I am getting an error while installing that setup to client system is" error unable to find version at runtime"

Comment: could this be .Net runtime version unavailablity?

Comment: It showing an error "unable to find a version at the runtime for this application"

Comment: I installed dotnet framework 4.0 on client system before installation of the application

Comment: may you check this thread: [.Net framework - “unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335133/net-framework-unable-to-find-a-version-of-the-runtime-to-run-this-applicatio?rq=1)

Comment: are you using click once deployment?

Comment: @ Alex, the link is good, in my application their is no any backend database. The above link is good if we use database to our applicatiion otherwise it doesn't work